# How to mock a OPC UA Session for unit testing in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, opc-ua, unified-automation-sdk

I have a C# application, which includes a service that works with multiple OPC UA Sessions ([UnifiedAutomation.UaClient.Session](http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkdotnet/2.0.0/L2ClientSdkSession.html)). These sessions are created by connecting to addresses like opc.tcp://localhost:48030 etc.

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connectionSettings in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    var connectionString = connectionSettings.ConnectionString;

    // Ignore non-OPC-connections 
    if (!connectionString.StartsWith("opc.tcp")) continue;

    // Create new session for connection
    var session = new Session
    {
        AutomaticReconnect = true,
        ReconnectDelay = 0
    };

    // Connect to OPC UA Server
    try
    {
        session.Connect(connectionString, SecuritySelection.None);
        Log("OPC UA Session establish.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
    catch (StatusException)
    {
        Log($"No OPC UA Server found at {connectionString}.",
            EventLogEntryType.Warning);
    }
}
```

I want to **unit test** the methods of my service but I cannot figure out how to **mock the OPC UA sessions**.

Any idea if this is possible at all?

Comment: Are you using those like usual tcp connections or via a client lib? If client lib: which one and do you inject it via DI? Can you post a code example?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Fildor. They are actual TCP connections.

Comment: OK. Maybe there is a better way, but personally, I'd create some Factory for `Session` instead of using `new Session` directly, so I could inject another implementation (= Mock). Then it would be testable. Or, since the instance seems always to have the same params, I'd inject a Session instance via DI if you have DI (Dependency Injection) in place anyway.

Comment: @jasie did you manage to do this?

Comment: @JTIM Sorry, no, but if I remember correctly, I did not try the proposal of Fildor. Maybe you can give it a go?

Comment: I can't test it, but this lib might be useful: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/tree/master/Tests